# issue when set parent form valid manually by setting each child form field valid

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have nested and repeated forms on UI.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="Registration">
  <form ng-repeat = "s in students" name="studentRegisteration">
     <input type="number" id="input" name="input" model="input" ng-change="validate()">
  </form>
</form>
```

I am trying `$setValidity()` for a specific field of child form as following

```
$scope.validate = function (index) {
    if (condition true)
     $scope.Registration.studentRegisteration.input.$setValidity('integer', false);
}
```

**It works fine until** i have one form on UI i.e. successfully set integer (property) valid and eventually parent forms become valid.

**It does not work** when i have multiple forms on UI... The parent forms does not become valid... i am not sure how to set field valid for individual child form so that parent becomes valid.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you pass the form controller in the function parameter for `validate` it will work. Something like

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="Registration">
  <form ng-repeat = "s in students" name="studentRegisteration">
     <input type="number" id="input" name="input" model="input" ng-change="validate(Registration.studentRegisteration)">
  </form>
</form>
```

Code:

```
$scope.validate = function (form) {
    if (condition true)
     form.input.$setValidity('integer', false);
}
```

I am not sure if you pass  `Registration.studentRegisteration` or `studentRegisteration`, try both

Comment: Okay, let me try this.

Comment: excellent man. It works absolutely fine. FYI, i passed studentRegisteration so no need to pass Registration.studentRegisteration. thanks